# Would you write this sentence : "there is nothing a busy man is less busied with than living"?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

This is a quote from [Seneca’s essay “On the Shortness of Life”](http://www.forumromanum.org/literature/seneca_younger/brev_e.html). I find this sentence a little complicated.

> There is nothing the busy man is less busied with than living; there is nothing that is harder to learn.

What is the meaning of *there is nothing* here?

Why can't we write:

- There is no busy man less busied than living.

Comment: Since it must be a translation, a link to the translation would be useful (or at least a citation and a more substantial quote). The sentence could be made easier to parse if it read "...is less busied **with** than living." Is it an accurate transcription? Perhaps a misprint in the edition you're using? We need to be able to determine those questions too.

Comment: You could write that but it wouldn't mean the same thing.  And you could reword the original to something similar to that, but it would lose much of it's emotional impact.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "there is nothing" is that *there simply is no thing* a busy man is less concerned with than with living. Ie, he is concerned with all manner of things far more than with the task of living. It is the task of living (and we'd need more of the context to decide what Seneca means by that) that is so hard to learn that people will add more and more tasks to their list of things to do before concerning themselves with how to live.